# Concatenate video frames using AvgPooling

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, data-science

I have features extracted from 4 images. These images are video frames. And i want to combine them into one vector of shape (1 ,768) or (1, 512) 
Is AvgPooling the best way to do it?

```py
import torch
input = torch.rand([1, 4, 768])
sumpool = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 512))
sumpool(input).shape #torch.Size([1, 1, 512])
```

Also i tried MeanPooling:

```py
result = torch.sum(visual_output, dim=1) / 4 #(1, 768)
```

But seems like i wrong somewhere. After using these combined features results are worse. Is everything correct?

Comment: that *highly* depends on... what turns out to work better. try all, compare. the result of the pooling has to be useful to the following layers. -- pooling does not concatenate, it pools. if you need concatenation, you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive average pool adjusts sizes for pooling regions whereas mean pooling is similar to AvgPool2d, it solves by dividing the input feature map into several non-overlapping regions and computing the average of each region, assuming your input size is always different from output size created we get irregular results. Basic Pooling had this problem that is why Adaptive pooling came into being.

Comment: As input to concatenation step i always have 4 vectors of the same size(1,768). I combine them into Tensor of shape (4,768) and do MeanPooling(second code) for this Tensor